# TweenMax animate part of an Image (GSAP)

Tags: jquery, animation, gsap

I am trying to highlight/box-shadow buttons from an image. For example I have this image -

https://static.gosquared.com/images/liquidicity/17_08_18_cta_03.png

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .no-gutter{
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    .demo {
      position:relative;
    }
    .line-white
    {
      position: absolute;
      background-color:#fc9e04;
      width: 420px;
      height:1px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .analytics_img {
      width: 900px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var tl = new TimelineLite({delay:0.5})
     TweenMax.set('#lineRight', {marginTop:270, left:400});
     tl.addLabel("start");
     tl.from("#lineRight", 1, {scaleX:0, transformOrigin:"left"}, "start");
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="revenue_section">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="demo">
          <div class="line-white" id="lineRight"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <img class="analytics_img" src="https://static.gosquared.com/images/liquidicity/17_08_18_cta_03.png"
          alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to highlight Buy Now buttons one after another. Highlight nothing but move up the button and increase size and apply shadow.

Is it possible?

If yes, how to do that? help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an svg instead of a png. I know there are some tools online that you can use to convert pngs into svgs but I'm not sure how good they are. You can also create svgs with photoshop and gimp and I've also used this handy online editor for making simple ones... http://www.drawsvg.org/

Hope that helps!